# How to use an existing dal to log with a log4net appender using spring dependency injection

Tags: .net, spring, inversion-of-control, log4net, appender

I'm working on an application that uses Spring to instantiate concrete classes and use `NHibernate` as an ORM.

I'm trying to create an appender for log4net that use the already existing DAL (`LogDao : ILogDao`) but the class must be injected by spring in the appender implementation.

I don't want to write my query in the configuration file like I know I could. 
It defeats the purpose of having a DAL in my opinion.

I have the impression that it is log4net that instantiate the appender so the spring dependency injection is not working (I can be wrong but it seems so).

Do I really need to use a service locator or are there any alternatives?

In my attempt below (simplified) I use a BLL but the problem is the same DAO or BLL.

```
namespace Application.Support.Log4net
{
    public class DatabaseAppender : AppenderSkeleton
    {
        private readonly ILogService _logService;

        public DatabaseAppender(ILogService logService)
        {
            _logService = logService;
        }

        protected void Log(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            Log message = ConvertToLogMessage(loggingEvent);

            _logService.SaveLog(message);

        }

        /// <summary>This is the main entry point for the Log4Net framework.</summary>
        /// <param name="loggingEvent">The event to append.</param>
        protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            try
            {
                if (loggingEvent == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("loggingEvent_");
                }

                Log(loggingEvent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorHandler.Error("An error occured while posting the provided event; unable to proceed.", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can [add an appender at runtime](http://dhvik.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/adding-appender-to-log4net-in-runtime.html), so when you create the appender you can inject the DAL into it.